# Using python to extract string from a file and put in order

Tags: python, string

I have a text file, populated with the following:

```
   "": "<a href=\"#\" class=\"tree-title\" title=\"IP: 10.0.0.1\nHostname: hello1\nModel: 2901\nVersion: 1.1.1.1_80000\nState: Normal\">hello1(10.0.0.1)</a>"
  },
  {
    "": "<a href=\"#\" class=\"tree-title\" title=\"IP: 10.0.0.2\nHostname: hello2\nModel: 2911\nVersion: 1.1.1.1_80000\nState: Normal\">hello2 (10.0.0.2)</a>"
  },
  {
    "": "<a href=\"#\" class=\"tree-title\" title=\"IP: 10.0.0.3\nHostname: hello3\nModel: 2911\nVersion: 1.1.1.1_80000\nState: Normal\">hello3(10.0.0.3)</a>"
  },
  {
```

It's not properly structured as it was scraped off and dumped into a text file.
There is over a 100 of such segments. 
Despite how it looks, the page was not in just html hence why I couldn't simply extract the data as a structured form.

Now I would like to use Python to extract just the `hostname, Model number` and `IP address` in an orderly list.

So it would look something like the following in new lines:

```
hostname: hello1       Model No: 2901       IP address: 10.0.0.1<br>
hostname: hello2       Model No: 2911       IP address: 10.0.0.2<br>
hostname: hello3       Model No: 2911       IP address: 10.0.0.3
```

But I struggle to find how to do this by firstly extracting the necessary info from the first segment, then the next etc.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try coding.  Try.

Comment: I think you need the magic of Regular expressions. [re module in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna fully answer this as you didn't show us any code. Rather I'll give you some hints that will help:

**The way I'd do it:**

1. `strip()` away any new-line character and any space from your file
2. use a regex to match the groups you need. You can use [**this one**](https://regex101.com/r/tjw72s/1)
3. Regex101 has also a nice way of generating the desired code in different languages so you'll be done after a bit of self-processing. (however, for learning purposes, I don't recommend it)
4. Look into `re` module and implement the above regex. You can [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this

Of course, you'll have to manage yourself how to handle opening of a file, reading its content, apply all the above on it and order the data however you like. Good luck.

[**Here's a starting point**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)